# Set Tooltips on and off in aspx with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tooltip

I'm using the ddimgtooltip.js in an aspx webpage to show tooltips.
I want to turn it on and off with a button on the aspx webpage.
So far I managed to get the button und have a hiddden field `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdf_Test" />` that changes its value by clicking the button and with that changed Value I want to toggle the Tooltips on and off.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you mean the button is asp.net server side control, using which you want to change the client side tooltip property then I'm afraid it's not the right thing to do. 
Adding a HiddenField/Label is a work around but not a solution. Check whether any option available in ddimgtooltip.js if there is an option available for this.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with "server side control" it's just a button on the page nothing special.
Yeah I know, but there is no real way in the javascript.
I guess my main problem ist to get the connenction between the aspx side and the Javascript file.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Let's elaborate for you.
ASPX - Server side control since they run on server side code.
JavaScript - Client side control.

Now controlling a client side property(e.g. - tooltip you are using here) is a difficult job since the scope of both the controls are different. 
I'd suggest you to use the Tooltip property of ASPX controls instead of JavaScript to have better control over it.